# Applying for Long stay visa as scientist - France with an I-20/EAD expiring soon

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, long-stay-visas

I will need to apply for a long stay visa as a scientist for a job in France starting May 12th 2014. I am NOT a US citizen, I am from India. I am on an F1 visa right now with an I-20/EAD that expires Aug 2014. One of the [requirements](http://www.consulfrance-chicago.org/spip.php?article484#requirements-4) for the long stay visa at the Chicago consulate is:

> If you are not a US citizen: residency card or valid visa to the
>   United States, I-20, IAP66, advanced parole or any other pertinent
>   documents from INS showing that you may reenter the U.S. + ONE COPY.

Clearly, my I-20/EAD expires in Aug 2014. Will this mean my application for a France long stay visa will be rejected? My US F1 visa expires Nov 2016 but I cannot enter the US on an F1 visa without an I-20! I am not planning on returning to the USA on an F1 visa anyway but is that secondary since I did not meet the requirement?

Does this mean that I will have to apply for a visa back in my home country of India?

Comment: This question would be off topic for this site and is better for [Expatriates](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) site when it comes live.  Since you're likely not going to be returning to the US you will likely not have to supply the permission to re-enter and follow the same procedure as [other Indian citizens do](http://www.ambafrance-in.org/SCIENTIST-RESEARCH-VISA) in the same case.  The difference being that you will be applying in Chicago instead of one of the consulates in India

Comment: Sincere apologies for "off-topic" question. The immigrant/expats SE hasn't "opened shop" yet and I am unable to find the correct answer to this question. (Although @Karlson provides some useful perspective)

Comment: @Karlson Sorry to continue with this thread but would you think I would need to provide documentation about my "unlikely return to USA"?

Comment: YOu don't have to be sorry to continue. The EXPATRIATES thing is not very helpful at the moment.

Comment: Most likely yes but this needs to be checked with the consulate.

Comment: @SantaC. Instead of bashing Expatriates not being helpful commit to it so it can move to beta and questions like this find the appropriate home and be answered properly.

Comment: @SantaC. There are areas of overlap but migration and immigration isn't the same as travel.  And it seems that the community doesn't share your feeling on the subject: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/10023/visa-immigration-a-subset-of-travel-se  And if you feel that what I said was trolling you're welcome to flag it let the mods act on it.